# PHP getting the name of the caller page

Tags: php

I have a php collection script, PHP-Assets.php
It contains my most often used parts of code that i like to keep in a general location.

Other php pages use an include statement they call that page and call some of the functions in it depending on the page.

No i'm looking for a way to retrieve the name of the file that called PHP-Assets.php
So i can build code that would be available depending on the caller page.
So index.php; uses PHP-Assets, and PHP-Assets would know that it was index.php which is currently on display at the user side; and because it knows that can return a different answer in a function.

Comment: That sounds like the beginning of a broken abstraction.  If there is functionality that's specific to *only* `index.php` then shouldn't that functionality exist *on* `index.php` (or on another file used only by that one page) rather than in shared code?  Generic operations go in shared code.

Comment: Well i'm working inside my own web framework, and in there i prefer to keep out all kind of code when creating a page, not much more then table and image and texts is visible in those pages, everything else is done by calling php. some of my "widgets" need to know the page name to know the difference between a main menu page or a sub menu page. it sounds complex but editing the pages is quite simple because one doesnt see all kind of code in it. its almost notepad html editing now :)

Answer (score 2):

For this php has the superglobal `$_SERVER`. With `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` you get the name of the script requested by the user (index.php e.g.).

Hope that is, what you want. But maybe a better way is, that you give the name of the script (or only the relevant data?) via a function parameter only to these functions, they need it.

Comment: I've been thinking about that.. the point is i never know where people enter my site. And when entering my site nothing is called yet i think..or does it ?.. /// maybe that could work tough, ill try it because i like that 2nd idea better.